# Organizing files in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a social media web application. Users upload pictures such as profile picture, project pictures, and etc. What's the best way to organize these files in a S3 bucket?

I thought of creating a folder with `userid` as its name inside the bucket and the inside that multiple other folders i.e. profile, projects and etc.

Not sure if that's the best approach to follow!

Comment: This question is really too broad. It's your call. Either have a folder for each `userid` or have one for each of the other elements and differentiate by `userid` within those. The important thing to remember is to [mimic a filesystem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/organize-s3.html).

Comment: Remember there are no "folders" in S3. It has flat structure with all objects being identified with a key. This can be helpful to keep in mind when designing key structures. More herehttps://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html

Answer (score 5):

The names (Keys) you assign an object in Amazon S3 are frankly irrelevant.

What matters is that you have a **database that tracks the objects**, their ownership and their purpose.

You should not use the filename (Key) of an Amazon S3 object as a way of storing information about the object, because your application might have millions of objects in S3 and it is too slow to scan the list of objects to see which ones exist. Instead, consult a database to find them.

**To answer your question:** Yes, create a prefix by username if you wish, but then just give it a unique name (eg a [Universally unique identifier - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)) that avoids name clashes.

Answer (score 2):

Earlier there used to be a need to add random prefixes for better performance. More details [here](http://blog.gyanmatrix.com/s3-best-practices/) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-performance-tips-tricks-seattle-hiring-event/).

Following is the extract from one of that pages

Pay Attention to Your Naming Scheme If:

> **Distributing the Key names**
>
> Don’t save your object's key name starts with a date or standard key
>   names, it improves complexity in the S3 indexing and will reduce
>   performance, because based on the indexing objects saves in the single
>   storage partition .
>
> Amazon S3 maintains keys lexicographically in its internal indices.

However, as of [17 Jul 2018 announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/amazon-s3-announces-increased-request-rate-performance/), adding random prefix to S3 key isn't required for improving the performance